# How to compute a 2x2 Homography out of 3 corresponding points?

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry

In 1D projective geometry,
I want to compute the 2x2 Homography matrix $H$ (in homogeneous coordinates), given 3 pairs of corresponding points.

i.e. I want to find H such that:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
h_{11} &  h_{12}\\
h_{21} & h_{22}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a & a+b\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)   = 
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 &a' &a'+b'\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right).$$

However, I've got 6 equations here and only 3 unknowns. 
(dof(H) = 4 elements less one for scaling = 3).

I thought about 3 scaling factors that would add up to 6 unknowns, s.t. we would have a unique solution. But how exactly do I insert the scaling factors into the matrices and how can I compute H then?

Do you have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is mathematically correct, however I figured out another way to solve this equation, which leads to a simpler result.

I applied the technique for 2D projective geometry, which is described [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=si3R3Pfa98QC&pg=PA35) to the 1D case and it works out fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the result should be in the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & k_2a' & k_3(a'+b')\\
k_1 & k_2 & k_3
\end{array}\right)$$
with $k_1,k_2,k_3$ nonzero, to account for the homogeneous coordinates. Remember that the projective point $[x:y]$ is the same as the point $[kx:ky]$. So the middle answer doesn't have to look like $[a':1]$, it can be any of the other representations of the point, hence $[k_2a':k_2]$. That gives you three "scaling" factors. Is that what you were hoping for?